# Find a particular item in an object tree using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of cars.Every car has a list of passengers.

How do I use Linq to find the Car that has a passenger with the Social security number 999-99-9999?

This is how far I got.

```
var Passenger= Cars.SelectMany(c => c.Passengers).Where(p => p.SSN == "999-99-9999");
```

This gives me the passenger. But I want the car that this passenger is in.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: It depends on how you've constructed the Car and Passenger objects and how they are related. Can you post them, and we'll help you with the Linq to parse them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a query like this:

```
var selectedCars = cars.Where(c => c.Passengers.Any(p => p.SSN == "999-99-9999"));
```

If you want a single car that has the passenger, you can use `FirstOrDefault()`

```
var car = cars.Where(c => c.Passengers.Any(p => p.SSN == "999-99-9999"))
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

This will return null (or default value if Car is a value type) if there is no car found.

Comment: Proposing `FristOrDefault`, you should mention what happens if there is no such car

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a variable `List<Car> cars`

and `Car` exposes a property

`List<Passenger> Passengers`

and `Passenger` exposes a property `string SSN`

```
var p = cars.Where(s => s.Passengers.Any(p => p.SSN == "999-99-9999"))
```

Comment: probably because of syntax in the last sentence